# Sticky top bar rendering issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let me cut to the chase. It's on this site: http://www.smb.nu/wip/kampanj/

The white bar with the links is supposed to stick to the top when scrolled past, this effect is achieved with some simple jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#floater').toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > 129);
    $('#quote').toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > 129);
});
```

So far, so good (I believe). The css classes look like so:

```
#floater.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
div#quote.sticky {
    padding-top: 78px;
}
```

This works just fine in Firefox (OS X and Windows), and even in IE (gasp!). However, in Chrome (OS X and Windows) as well as Safari (OS X), it flickers, disappears and reappears, every so often. This despite Chrome's web inspector telling me it's there ([screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2355649/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-09%20at%2014.40.11%20.png)).

What the hell is going on? Did I stumble upon a WebKit rendering bug with fixed positioning (seems highly unlikely), or make some basic beginner's mistake? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It works on my Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95m (Windows). What's your version?

Comment: @Harshad that's interesting, I am seeing the same issue in Chrome 30.0.1588.0 and my OS is Windows8.

Comment: Okay, this is getting seriously odd. I have the same version (28.0.1500.95 m) on both the Windows computers I'm testing on. On one it's working now, on one it isn't.

My macbook is running 28.0.1500.95 and on that one it still won't work. Gonna try clearing out all caches and cookies and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the -webkit-filter: blur(0px); off of #uberwrapper the header functions correctly.

Comment: I think it has something to do with hardware rendering when using the blur. If you apply -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); to enable hardware rendering on the header it will display with the blur enabled on uberwrapper

Comment: oddly enough this still exists in 2022. Position sticky of a header (flex) that contains dropdowns. When dropdown triggers scroll (in specific widow size) content gets blurred. filter:blur(0px) solves it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
```

to the parent container should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on chrome's console... Don't ask me why, I think it triggers some gpu's calculation and seems to fix it. But that's a dirty workaround wich may breaks in a near future.

Comment: You sir, get a plus one.

Comment: I could use the fix on the console too. But I couldn't get it working inside my `scroll` events function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using pure css, why you need jquery?

http://jsfiddle.net/SRpA4/

```
.header-cont {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
height:50px;
background-color:#C00;
```

}

Comment: It's only supposed to stick to the top when you scroll below its original position.

Comment: `position:sticky` will be the future. But it's currently only supported by webKit / Safari

Answer (score 0):

I think chrome may have made a change recently to the way it renders position:fixed. I haven't got a clue what they've done or why it's not working for you corrently, but I do have a solution that is probably better because it will work on mobiles too (many mobiles don't support fixed positioning).

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 129 ) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#floater').addClass('sticky').css('top',scrollTop);
  }
  else { $('#floater').removeClass('sticky'); }
});
```

CSS

```
#floater.sticky {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug. The `-webkit-filter: blur(0px);` for #uberwrapper seems to be causing the issue.

Dont know the exact reason behind it.
But an easy fix would be to Remove `-webkit-filter: blur(0px);`